# Visual Studio 2019, вопрос по обозревателю решений

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

Не могу понять, для чего обозреватель решений `Visual Studio 2019` имеет разделы `Исходные файлы` и `Файлы заголовков`.

Я пробовал перемещать заголовки/исходники по обоим разделам, ничего не изменилось.

Так же я провел эксперимент: поместил все `*.hpp` в раздел `Файлы заголовков`, а все `*.cpp` в раздел `Исходные файлы`. Все файлы при этом лежали в общей папке `source`. Запушил решение в `git`, затем скачал его обратно... После этой процедуры разделы `Исходные файлы` и `Файлы заголовков` пропали. Вместо них появился раздел `source`, где все лежало в куче.

Как это работает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не разделы а фильтры. Размещение файлов по ним ни на что не влияет. Это размещение хранится в файлах .filters, которые в репозитории можно добавлять, а можно и не добавлять.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.